# Разворот на более 360+ градусов

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Если задать примерно такой разворот:

```
Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 360 * A);
```

не важно что будет на месте A (из целых чисел) разворота никогда не будет, если же счисло будет типа A.5 (число с запятой где после запятой половина) то разворот будет ровно 180, из этого выходит что задать разворот на 3600 (т.е. 10 кругов) простым способом нельзя, у меня выполняеться плавный поворот круга, что бы я не писал всякий бред по типу считания каждого полукруга я задал вопрос: как сделать разворот на большое кол-во градусов (т.е. более одного целого круга):
мой код поворота:

```
        Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 1800);
    float t = 5f;
    float tA = Time.time;
    while (t > 0)
    {
        t -= Time.time - tA;
        tA = Time.time;
        Debug.Log(t);
        transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, quaternion, (5-t)/5f);
        yield return 0;
    }
```

кстати, тут еще я хотел поворот ровно за 5 секунд, но почему-то (в силу моей незнанности оно работает не верно).

**Главный вопрос:** как сделать разворот (в моем случае плавный) на несколько кругов, по типу на 3600 градусов т.е. 10 кругов.

Второй же вопрос, как сделать разворот ровно за конкретное кол-во времени

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html    https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Comment: @ValeraKvip зачем мне это?

Comment: 1. Как один из способов вращать. 2. Как в сопрограммах сделать задержку на Х секунд. 3. Проблема не ясна, что в коде не работает? Какой должен быть разворот - плавный или мгновенный? Что конкретно не получилось?  Задайте внизу поста вопрос, что бы было понятно в чем конкретно  нужна помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вся проблема заключается в том, что вращение вокруг любой оси **физически ограничено** и находится в промежутке `[0;360)`, если речь идет о градусах. Но не надо путать: мы можем повернуть объект хоть на миллиард градусов - в конце концов он все равно будет иметь поворот в промежутке `[0;360)`.

Да и проверить это на практике довольно просто, сделаем так:

```
Debug.Log(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 1800).eulerAngles);
Debug.Log(Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 1799).eulerAngles);
```

Смотрим на вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходя из написанного выше, использовать "референсное" значение для поворота таким образом не получится.

---

Подобное можно реализовать через фиксированный поворот:

```
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 rotationStep = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    public float time = 0;

    IEnumerator RotateForSeconds(float seconds, Vector3 step) {
        while(seconds > 0) {
            seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Rotate(step * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RotateForSeconds(time, rotationStep));
    }
}
```

А дальше простейшие расчеты:

Нужно повернуть объект на 360 градусов за 10 секунд? Значит, нам нужна скорость в 360/10 = 36 градусов в секунду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно повернуть объект на 1800 градусов за 5 секунд? Повторяем действия выше: 1800/5 = 360:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А вообще для всего, что связано с **ручной анимацией**, лучше использовать [LeanTween](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/leantween-3595) или любой другой tween engine. Но проблема в том, что такие движки работают с "референсными" значениями, что нам не особо подходит из рассуждений выше, но как дополнительную информацию все же оставлю.

[Залезаем в документацию](http://dentedpixel.com/LeanTweenDocumentation/classes/LeanTween.html#method_LeanTween.rotate):

> LTDescr rotate(GameObject gameObject, Vector3 to, float time) Defined
>   in LeanTween.cs:1481
>
> Rotate a GameObject, to values are in passed in degrees

Comment: Начал писать что-то подобное, но теперь уже не буду, плюс вам!

Comment: Справедливости ради, все это можно заменить LeanTween'ом - надо бы добавить про это в ответ. А за плюс спасибо :)

Comment: Да, и топик стартеру тоже плюс, раз собирался писать ответ =)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а если нужно плавно? типа набрать скорость и потом скинуть?

Comment: Меняйте скорость поворота по синусоиде в корутине.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker это без LeanTween, только вашим способом? Как сменить скорость я знаю, но тогда же оно не проктутиться ровно до того момента которого мне нужно

Comment: @kitsoRik вам нужно менять скорость и при этом сделать поворот на определенный градус и за определенное время?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker да, вот так все сложно

Comment: @kitsoRik, ну тут нужно подумать, в LeanTween есть нечто подобное, но там используется референсное значение поворота.

Comment: @kitsoRik, я бы на вашем месте задал отдельный вопрос "как повернуть объект на X градусов за Y секунд, изменяя в процессе скорость вращения". Этот вопрос и ответ самодостаточны и не хочется их перегружать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker спасибо, я уже решил с помощью по синусоиде, правда время не точное, но это мне подходит

Comment: @kitsoRik, без дифференциального уравнения эту задачу "точно" не решить. Но, если вас все устраивает - то и запариваться не стоит :)